# How to access static property and static constants of another Class Dynamically

Tags: php, class, variables, static, constants

This is My PHP sample code, and i want to access static property of another class dynamically, basically i have class name that is stored inside a variable.

```
# Main Class
class HelloAction
{
    const FIRST = "DEMO";
    public static $first = "WORLD";
    function __construct($confclassname)
    {
        $this->config = $confclassname;
        # PHP Interpreter throws an Error for These Two Lines
        $this->first1 = $this->config::$a;
        $this->first2 = $this->config::$b;
    }

    function setFirst($s)
    {
        self::$first = $s;
    }
}

# Configuration Class
# Can hold only static or constants values
class action1
{
    const AAAA = "____Hello World____";
    public static $a = "this is an apple";
    public static $b = "That is an Dog";
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->second = "hi, there.";
    }
}

# Configuration Class
# Can hold only static or constants values
class action2
{
    const AAAA = "___Yeah, Hello World____";
    public static $a = "Whare You were...";
    public static $b = "Awesome work";
    function __construct()
    {

    }
    public static function action21($s)
    {
        self::$a = $s;
    }
    public function action22()
    {
        return self::$a;
    }
}

# We want to inject configuration Object into Main Class Object
$b1 = new HelloAction('action1');
$b2 = new HelloAction('action2');

echo $b1->first1 . "\n";
echo $b1->first2 . "\n";
```

> Error:
>   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM) in F:\xampp\htdocs\6-project-n_demos\011.php on line 11

Comment: after `class helloaction{` add `public static $config;`

Comment: @mega6382 - i tried by still does not work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

comment line `11` and `12` and try to `var_dump` `this->config` and you'll see that it is not picking the whole object but just the `__construct` because you are calling static methods on an object so try the following code

```
        class HelloAction
        {
            const FIRST = "DEMO";
            public static $first = "WORLD";
            function __construct($confclassname)
            {
                $this->config = $confclassname;
                # PHP Interpreter throws an Error for These Two Lines
                $this->first1 = $confclassname::$a;
                $this->first2 = $confclassname::$b;
            }

            function setFirst($s)
            {
                self::$first = $s;
            }
        }

        class action1
        {
            const AAAA = "____Hello World____";
            public static $a = "this is an apple";
            public static $b = "That is an Dog";
            function __construct()
            {
                $this->second = "hi, there.";
            }
        }

        class action2
        {
            const AAAA = "___Yeah, Hello World____";
            public static $a = "Whare You were...";
            public static $b = "Awesome work";
            function __construct()
            {

            }
            public static function action21($s)
            {
                self::$a = $s;
            }
            public function action22()
            {
                return self::$a;
            }
        }

        $b1 = new HelloAction('action1');
        $b2 = new HelloAction('action2');

        echo $b1->first1 . "\n";
        echo $b1->first2 . "\n";

        ?>
```

Comment: thanks but,  `action1` and `action2` class properties are either static or constants

Comment: than you'll have to use it as `action1::$a` instead of `$this->config::$a`

Answer (score 0):

The line where it gives error should be

```
$this->first1 = $confclassname::$a;
$this->first2 = $confclassname::$b;
```

It does not allow `$this->config` to be written as a class name. It requires a variable.

If you write `$this->config::$a;` then the interpreter might think of it as a `$this->` and `config::$a;`. It treats config as a property here and gives error when founds that there is a scope resolution operator next to a property.

I tried it encapsulating it in curly braces like this `{$this->config}::$a`. Still it does not work. So I would suggest to only use variables to define the class name.

Comment: thanks but this is like extracting information form class, what if i want to access this `$this->config` variable inside any class method

Comment: `$this->config` is not a variable. Its a property of the same class you are in. Also we cannot just access or jump to any variable outside the class without letting the code know where exactly to go. You need to specify the class it needs to pick. `$this->config` can be accessed anywhere inside the class though. But here you are accessing it in improper way. As i explained earlier in the answer, `$this->config` can be interpreted in different ways. so be careful with these.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my `HelloAction` class code a little, This is solution that works the way i wanted it to be, Now i can access each and every static property, constants, everywhere inside Class and Class Methods.

```
class HelloAction
{
    const FIRST = "DEMO";
    public static $first = "WORLD";
    function __construct($confclassname)
    {
        $this->config = new $confclassname();
        $this->configRefObj = new ReflectionClass($this->config);
        $this->first1 = $this->configRefObj->getStaticPropertyValue("a");
        $this->first2 = $this->configRefObj->getStaticPropertyValue("b");
    }

    function setFirst($s)
    {
        self::$first = $s;
    }
}
```